# Option label as var in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="wbox" name="listbox" size="20"onchange="call(this)">
<optgroup label="Taxes">
<option value="1694" label="DNA-option1"></option>
<option value="1642">RNA-option2</option>
```

I have a list box that I would like to extract the label of the selected option, and use it in a JavaScript function.

```
function call(op) {
        alert(op.label); 
        alert(op.name); 
        alert(op.value); 

        var x = op.label;          
     }
```

However this always returns as label, undefined. I've tried changing the way the option label is written in the html. This might not be the best way to write the java script function. I absolutely cannot use the option value, it is a unique id and used for something else. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `op.selectedOptions[0]`?

Comment: .textContent at the end of that and its perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected `<option>`, you need to use the `selectedOptions` property. This is an array, because `<select>` tags can (optionally) support multiple selection. This array contains `<option>` tag objects, so you should be able to get your label using `op.selectedOptions[0].textContent`.

Comment: op.selectedOptions[0].textContent isn't working in Firefox17 or IE9

Comment: Then `op.getElementsByTagName("option")[op.selectedIndex].textContent` should do it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess:

```
    <select id="wbox" name="listbox" size="20" onchange="call(this.selectedOptions)">
        <optgroup label="Taxes">
            <option value="1694" label="DNA-option1">RNA-option1</option>
            <option value="1642" label="DNA-option2">RNA-option2</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function call(op){
            for(var i=0;i<op.length;i++){
                console.log('Label: '+ op[i].getAttribute('label'));
            }
        }
    </script>
```